# Solving ordinary differential equation $x^{\prime\prime}+x=\sin t+e^{2t} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The question is:
$$x^{\prime\prime}+x=\sin t+e^{2t} $$
I have tried to solve it like this:
$$r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i $$
The answer to the homogeneous equation is:
$$x_h(t)=C_1\cos t + C_2\sin t $$
but I don't know how should I find the particular solution I have tried with
$$ x_p=A\cos t + B\sin t + Ce^{2t} $$
but I didn't get the right answer, any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** try $$x_p= t(A\cos t + B\sin t) + Ce^{2t}$$ The reason is that you already have a sine component in the homogeneous solution, so need to multiply the trig part of the solution by $t$. For more details, see [*Undetermined Coefficients*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Moo

Answer (score 1):

You can find the particular solution as follows
$$x_p=\frac{\sin t+e^{2t}}{D^2+1}\quad (\text{where}, \ D=\frac{d}{dt})$$
$$=\frac{\sin t}{D^2+1}+\frac{e^{2t}}{D^2+1}$$
$$=t\frac{\sin t}{\frac{d}{dD}(D^2+1)}+\frac{e^{2t}}{2^2+1}\quad (\because \ -1^2+1=0)$$
$$=t\frac{\sin t}{2D}+\frac{e^{2t}}{5}$$
$$=\frac{t}{2}D\left(\frac{\sin t}{D^2}\right)+\frac{e^{2t}}{5}$$
$$=\frac{t}{2}D\left(\frac{\sin t}{-1^2}\right)+\frac{e^{2t}}{5}$$
$$=\color{blue}{-\frac{t}{2}\cos t+\frac{e^{2t}}{5}}$$

Note: Standard formula used to find particular solutions

$$\boxed{x_p=\frac{\sin at}{D^2+b}=\frac{\sin at}{-a^2+b}(\text{if}\ -a^2+b\ne0)}$$
$$\boxed{x_p=\frac{\sin at}{D^2+b}=t\frac{\sin at}{\frac{d}{dD}(D^2+b)}\ \ (\text{if}\ -a^2+b=0)}$$
$$\boxed{x_p=\frac{e^{at}}{D^2+b}=\frac{e^{at}}{a^2+b}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{\prime\prime}+x=\sin t+e^{2t}$$
For the particular solution, you should simply try:
$$x_p=At\cos t+Be^{2t}$$